# Summing up a very specific section of a usbtop command

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have gotten quite far in this issue, I have been able to filter out all of the information I need, but when it comes down to summing up the numbers, it runs but nothing prints.

Here's what I have. `sudo usbtop` vomits everything like so:

```
$sudo usbtop 
Bus ID 0 (All USB buses)    To device    From device
  Device ID 1 :            0.00 KiB/s    0.00 KiB/s
  Device ID 5 :            119.42 KiB/s    29620.68 KiB/s
  Device ID 7 :            133.55 KiB/s    30097.61 KiB/s
  Device ID 8 :            146.48 KiB/s    30035.24 KiB/s
  Device ID 11 :            403.09 KiB/s    116395.06 KiB/s
  Device ID 13 :            145.12 KiB/s    30221.49 KiB/s
  Device ID 15 :            402.34 KiB/s    116173.13 KiB/s
  Device ID 17 :            408.02 KiB/s    117784.73 KiB/s
  Device ID 22 :            402.31 KiB/s    116166.17 KiB/s
  Device ID 24 :            402.57 KiB/s    116242.83 KiB/s
  Device ID 25 :            402.62 KiB/s    116255.38 KiB/s
  Device ID 26 :            14.44 KiB/s    7267.52 KiB/s
  Device ID 27 :            14.44 KiB/s    7267.78 KiB/s
  Device ID 28 :            12.08 KiB/s    6056.14 KiB/s
Bus ID 1 (USB bus number 1)    To device    From device
  Device ID 1 :            0.00 KiB/s    0.00 KiB/s
  Device ID 5 :            119.42 KiB/s    29620.57 KiB/s
  Device ID 7 :            133.55 KiB/s    30098.21 KiB/s
  Device ID 8 :            146.48 KiB/s    30035.24 KiB/s
  Device ID 13 :            145.12 KiB/s    30221.49 KiB/s
Bus ID 2 (USB bus number 2)    To device    From device
  Device ID 11 :            403.33 KiB/s    116470.63 KiB/s
  Device ID 15 :            401.87 KiB/s    116056.23 KiB/s
  Device ID 17 :            407.62 KiB/s    117657.41 KiB/s
  Device ID 22 :            401.91 KiB/s    116032.60 KiB/s
  Device ID 23 :            0.00 KiB/s    0.00 KiB/s
  Device ID 24 :            401.93 KiB/s    116068.74 KiB/s
  Device ID 25 :            402.19 KiB/s    116149.45 KiB/s
  Device ID 26 :            10.49 KiB/s    4707.21 KiB/s
  Device ID 27 :            11.77 KiB/s    5874.43 KiB/s
  Device ID 28 :            13.06 KiB/s    6518.48 KiB/s
```

usbtop with this grep pipe filters out the section I need:

```
$sudo usbtop | grep -A 10 "Bus ID 2"
Bus ID 0 (All USB buses)    To device    From device
--
Bus ID 2 (USB bus number 2)    To device    From device
  Device ID 11 :            390.70 KiB/s    112829.82 KiB/s
  Device ID 15 :            167.34 KiB/s    48399.99 KiB/s
  Device ID 17 :            397.52 KiB/s    114774.77 KiB/s
  Device ID 22 :            389.77 KiB/s    112561.07 KiB/s
  Device ID 24 :            390.87 KiB/s    112874.51 KiB/s
  Device ID 25 :            336.29 KiB/s    97280.79 KiB/s
  Device ID 26 :            13.07 KiB/s    6525.58 KiB/s
  Device ID 27 :            13.60 KiB/s    6786.53 KiB/s
  Device ID 28 :            11.35 KiB/s    5666.02 KiB/s
```

Adding an awk pipe can get the column I need, notice the column includes a few strings:

```
sudo usbtop | grep -A 10 "Bus ID 2"  | awk '{print $7}'

To

2)
116402.05
116149.45
116125.79
100062.28
118302.52
115981.20
6055.99
```

I can sort of filter out the strings by adding an if statement:

```
sudo usbtop | grep -A 10 "Bus ID 2"  | awk '{if ($1=="Device") print $7}'

116402.05
116149.45
116125.79
100062.28
118302.52
115981.20
6055.99
```

but this comment runs but returns nothing:

```
sudo usbtop | grep -A 10 "Bus ID 2"  | awk '{if ($1=="Device") sum+=$7} END {print sum}'
```

I am assuming that it is either getting caught up on the hidden strings, or it is continuously summing the incoming values without ending. My question is, how could I make it print what I need it to print? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Yes. `awk` `END` waits for EOF, which is not coming. I cannot find a documentation for `usbtop` if there exists something like `top -bn1`

Comment: I actually figured it out. It was a little complicated but this script worked: `sudo usbtop | grep -A 10 "Bus ID 2"  | awk '{if ($1 == "Device") sum+=$7} (NR%12==0){avg=sum/12;print $7"\nTotal: "sum "\tAverage: "avg;sum=0;next}'`

Comment: good. you may make this an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### My solution

I found a script that works for this issue.

```
sudo usbtop | grep -A 10 "Bus ID 2" | awk '{if ($1 == "Device") sum+=$7} (NR%12==0){avg=sum/12;print $7"\nTotal: "sum "\tAverage: "avg;sum=0;next}'
```

`{if ($1 == "Device") sum+=$7}` sums up the rows in column x if the value in column y returns true

`(NR%12==0)` counts every x rows

`{avg=sum/12;print $7"\nTotal: "sum "\tAverage: "avg;sum=0;next}` {calculates the average; prints the contents of column x; prints out the calculated results; resets the total to 0; and starts the next series of calculations}

I didn't need all of this information, so `{"\nTotal: "sum;sum=0;next}` was enough for me.

Sending it as a command through ssh:

```
ssh -t domain@hostIP -a "sudo usbtop | grep -A 12 'Bus ID 2'  | awk '{if(\$3>0) sum+=\$7/1000} (NR%10==0){print "'"Total: "'" sum;sum=0;next}'"
```

where `-t` opens a terminal session and `-a` pulls the results to your own machine before running the command locally (I couldn't find out how to run the command remotely), notice you have to escape nested quotes and the $ characters, so `" ' "` is needed for writing total as a string, and `\$` for the column references.

as a python command with output to file:

```
output_file = 'text.txt'
command = '''ssh -t domain@hostIP -a "usbtop | grep -A 10 'Bus ID 2'  | awk '{if(\$3>0) sum+=\$7} (NR%10==0){print "'"Total: "'" sum;sum=0;next}'" >>''' + output_file
```

You can write `sum+=\$7/1000` to convert usbtop outputs to megabytes and so on.

NOTE: You might have to run the command through python as root.

Comment: `usbtop` has a `--bus` parameter, which expects bus names like `usbmon0`. So `usbtop --bus usbmon2` should get you just bus 2. (And you can list available bus names with `usbtop --list`)